# Vert.x 3: Best practices for communicating through EventBus between Spring RestController and BackServer

Tags: spring, vert.x, event-bus

I am making a pilot project with vert.x 3 and I would like to ask for best practices or example code to use with Spring and EventBus.

The case is quite easy:

- there is an API Gateway that receives REST calls with Spring RestController.
- in the method associated to the call, I would like to use Vert.x EventBus to send a message to another application that listens the EventBus, then, this second application should send back the answer to the first application.

I have run the example on Evenbus Vert.x 3.2 but I can't understand how to send messages with arguments from a method.

Then I would like to ask what is the best practice for using Event Bus with Spring in order to have it as a Service.

Answer (score 1):

did your 2nd app receive message yet? Evenbus will only send byte[] or JsonObject. I use Protocol Buffer for eventbus message (just hate JsonObject everywhere)

this is my code to send & receive java Object, I convert it to Protocol Buffer -> byte[] & vice versa.

```
vertx.eventBus().send("worker.lunar", message.getBytes(), (AsyncResult<Message<byte[]>> reply) -> {
            DateMonthYear result = new DateMonthYear(reply.result().body());
            r.response()
                    .putHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
                    .end(Json.encodePrettily(result));
        });
```